# Deploying Heroku app--updating my code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

This is a basic, stupid question, but I configured my Rails app to deploy on Heroku, and I'm able to open the application from my Heroku account, etc. But when I want to change my code, do I need to re-deploy the whole application? I tried just committing/pushing to heroku master, but I get the error "fatal: remote end hung up unexpectedly." What should I do instead?

Also: am I supposed to run db:migrate BEFORE deploying/pushing?

Comment: You push to your repository - such as github - with 'git push'.  Then you push what's in the repository to heroku with 'git push heroku master'.  Once you've done it a couple of times it becomes very simple.  What command are you entering when you get the error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing stupid about a basic question, as everyone has to start somewhere.

The basic process with deploying a Rails app to Heroku is to:

1. Make changes
2. Add and Commit your changes (`$ git add files_changed.rb` & `$ git commit -m "make changes"`)
3. Push your changes to Heroku (`$ git push heroku master`)

This then pushes your code to the remote Heroku repository and redeploys your Rails application. If you have made any database migrations, you need to run:

```
$ heroku run rake db:migrate
```

This runs db:migrate on your heroku app - see how that works? :)

Running rake db:migrate locally simply migrates your local development database.

Comment: This makes sense. However, I rerouted the index page to a new view I made, and my changes show up correctly locally (in localhost:3000), but when I git add/commit/push (and it shows up in Heroku that I correctly deployed). However, I still get the "Welcome aboard/You’re riding Ruby on Rails!" page when I open the app in Heroku. Any ideas?

Comment: Nvm...forgot to remove the public/index.html file in Git. thank you for your help!!